# Umbraco installation wizard Error - Could not connect to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I'm trying to install Umbraco on an ASP.NET environment. After I downloaded the umbraco nuget package I tried to run the installation wizard, by building and running the project. All is fine and good, if i take the default database configuration, but if I want to customize my configuration, it fails and says :

> "Could not connect to database"

I'm trying to configure it to use my local SQLExpress database, but I just cannot get it working. I have both tried putting in the server information and connecting via. a connection string, via. the wizard. It produces the same error every time.

I have made a database called **umbracoblog** and created an **admin** user, with credentials. He has **dbowner** etc. for the database. Besides that, I have also given full permissions to **IIS_IUSRS** and **Network Service accounts** for the project and all subdirectories, and it still doesn't work.

These are some of the connection strings I have tried:

```
datalayer=SqlServer;Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=umbracoblog;User Id=admin;Password=********;

datalayer=SqlServer;Data Source=127.0.0.1\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=umbracoblog;User Id=admin;Password=*******;
```

I have also tried putting in the connectionstring into the web.config, manually, but that just makes the project load infinitely in the browser, when I run it.

It's starting to get frustrating, that I cannot even get past the configuration of Umbraco, because it look very cool. I have tried everything I was able to found online. Have anyone gone through this and know what I need to do ?

Comment: When I have had problems using the "Microsoft SQL Server" database type in the installation wizard with Umbraco, it was because the placeholder text in the wizard was misleading. When it asks you for the "Server", it says to use a forward slash like this `127.0.0.1/SQLEXPRESS`. You should use a backslash like `127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS`. I've experienced this up to umbraco 7.2.8. What version of umbraco are you trying to install?

Comment: Oh sorry, im not at my computer right now, but im pretty sure it's the newest one, via NuGet :) I have been really busy at work, but i'm hoping to try these things out today or tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start again - clear out and remove the umbracoDbDSN connection string entirely from your web.config and reset the umbracoConfigurationStatus AppSetting back to empty if it has been populated.

Use the Wizard to configure the database - if it's still having problems connecting then here's a few things to check:

1. Check the Log file here: ~/App_Settings/Logs/UmbracoTraceLog.txt - does that show up any errors?
2. Make sure you can connect to the database using other clients - if Umbraco can't connect to it, chances are something else won't be able to as well.
3. What happens if you use Integrated Authentication?  If that works, then it's most likely an issue with the username and password you specified.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the late reply. I will try this is during the next couple days and respond back. thanks!

Comment: Didn't dawn on me that *setting* the connection string to start flagged Umbraco to assume the database was already created.......sigh.  Clearing and using wizard fixed it for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The password I had for the SQL Server user had a character that the installation UI didn't accept. I changed the password to remove special characters and it was able to connect to the server again. I could successfully log in through SSMS with the previous password.